# Argparse multiple values with options

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am using argparse for argument parsing in Python script. In this case I have two values where I got from using `narg=2`.
But the problem is when printing help. Below is part of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My App')
parser.add_argument('--add',default=None, action='store',help='Add new value', nargs=2,metavar='name')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Output for above code is :

```
$ python3 sshconfig.py list --help usage: sshconfig.py [-h] [--add NAME NAME]

My App

optional arguments:   -h, --help       show this help message and exit
--add NAME NAME  Add new value
```

I need to differentiate between argument of `--add` like `NAME` and `VALUE`, like below.

```
$ python3 sshconfig.py list --help usage: sshconfig.py [-h] [--add NAME VALUE]

My App

optional arguments:   -h, --help       show this help message and exit
--add NAME VALUE  Add new value
```

Comment: Have you tried the `metavar` parameter?  `megavar=('NAME', 'VALUE')`

Comment: @hpaulj This works. I tried `metavar=['name','value']` but it didn't worked. !!! Thanks

Comment: the use a tuple is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add multiple labels, set metavar to a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) that has a value for each argument.

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My App')
parser.add_argument('--add', help='Add new value', nargs=2, metavar=('name', 'VALUE'))

args = parser.parse_args()
```

output:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [--add name VALUE]

My App

optional arguments:
  -h, --help        show this help message and exit
  --add name VALUE  Add new value
```